# Why do I get deprecation warnings about Rails 2.3-style plugins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, plugins, asset-pipeline, deprecation-warning

I had a vendor directory/ directgory with /javascript and /plugins but they were empty and so I also deleted them.

I did git add --all and pushed the deletion but I still get the warning messages:

```
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_97dea2eb
-3f5c-4dc6-9455-2f0aa0cab7de/Rakefile:7)
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_97dea2eb
-3f5c-4dc6-9455-2f0aa0cab7de/Rakefile:7)
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_97dea2eb
-3f5c-4dc6-9455-2f0aa0cab7de/Rakefile:7)
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move the
m out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes 
for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_97dea2eb
-3f5c-4dc6-9455-2f0aa0cab7de/Rakefile:7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Rails 3 then Heroku inject plugins into your code at deploy time - you can prevent this from occurring by adding

```
gem rails_12factor
```

to your gemfile, bundling, committing and repushing. This is documented [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#injected-plugins)

Answer (score 0):

What does

```
git ls-files vendor/*
```

Show? If it shows files in there then you still have files in there.